# Data is not populated when passed as props

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-props

I am fetching data from an API using async and await in the stack navigator of my app. I want to use that data and pass it in the `initialParams` of my screens. However, when calling the data in the screen using props, I am getting an empty array. I also don't want to fetch the API directly on the screen. Is this the correct way to do this?

**HomeScreen.tsx**

```
const HomeScreen = ({
  navigation,
  route,
}: StackNavigationProps<Routes, "HomeScreen">) => {

    const data = route.params.data //?
    return (
       <Text>{data}</Text>
    )
}
```

**Data.tsx**

```
export const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const {
      data: { countries },
    } = await axios.get("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries");

    return countries.map((country) => country.name);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

**StackNavigator.tsx**

```
type AppStackRoutes = {
  HomeScreen: { data: any[] };
  DataScreen: undefined;
};

const AppStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MainStackNavigator = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAPI = async () => {
      setData(await fetchData());
    };
    fetchAPI();
  }, [setData]);

  return (
    <AppStack.Navigator>
      <AppStack.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
        initialParams={{ data: data }}
        options={{
          title: "Home",
        }}
      />

      <AppStack.Screen
        name="DataScreen"
        component={DataScreen}
        options={{
          headerBackTitle: "Summary",
          title: "Data",
        }}
      />
    <AppStack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

**Navigation.ts**

```
import { ParamListBase, RouteProp } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { StackNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/stack";

export interface StackNavigationProps<
  ParamList extends ParamListBase,
  RouteName extends keyof ParamList = string
> {
  navigation: StackNavigationProp<ParamList, RouteName>;
  route: RouteProp<ParamList, RouteName>;
  data: any[]
}

export type Routes = {
  HomeScreen: { data: any[] };
  DataScreen: undefined;
};
```

Comment: Don't you mean `const { countries } = await axios.get("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries")`? Based on the response of that endpoint, `countries` should be a key in the parsed JSON. Check your browser console. Does it show a warning?

Comment: No, it should be working. I'm just fetching the names of all the countries, and `countries` is not a key. It is the object's name.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial empty array is being passed. Meany there's no state update. If your API correctly returns the payload, then it's likely an async issue in useEffect. Try changing it like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchAPI = async () => {
    const data = await fetchData();
    setData(data);
  };
  fetchAPI();

}, []);
```

Comment: Still an empty array. I updated the code to include the routes of the stack navigator if that matters. I should be calling `data` using route.params right?